# how does angular compile attribute into directives at a later time

Tags: angularjs, compilation, attributes

I want to be able to have the second directive *phone* compiled to alert, how should I do this

```
<div ng-app="website">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">    
        <div phonebook="phone">  PhoneBook</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/aPWg8/

Comment: In your fiddle, clicking on `Phone` in the HTML fires the alert.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: sry, I forgot to add the updates. its changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `phone2` directive, you have this code:

```
e.html($compile(e.html())(s))
```

But `e.html()`, which you are compiling, isn't what you think. With a `console.log` just above the line,

```
console.log("HTML:", e.html());
```

you get the output

```
HTML: Phone
```

However, you can't just `$compile(e)` because that results in an infinite loop; you'd need to restructure your directives.

Comment: right is there a way to perform compile on the fly with a function htmlCompiled()